# Making a random path between vertices

Tags: modeling

I would like to make random path between 2 vertices.

When I press J, it cuts faces. I would like that path chooses already exsisting edges between 2 vertices.

Is it possible to do that without selecting it ?

[image]

Comment: Not random, but ctrl+clic will select the shortest path between the two vertices

Comment: I mean the paths should be on the cube.

Comment: Yes : select a single vertice, maintain Ctrl, then select a second vertice. The path follow the existing topology (but again, not random)